# Remove div with specific children dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have many numbers of divisions in my HTML code. There are no ids or classes for any of the divs. This is my code

```
<div>
<span>
<a href="#">
  link</a>
</span>
</div>

<div>
<span>
<span title=" title 1">
Some text written here
</span>
</span>
</div>

<div>
<span>
<span title="title 2">
Some other text written here
</span>
</span>
</div>

<div>
<span>
<a href="#">
some link
</a>
</span>
</div>
```

I want to get the text of innermost span inside divs, which have two nested spans and the innermost span should have a title such as

```
<div>
<span>
<span title="title 2">
Some other text written here
</span>
</span>
</div>
```

and also is it possible to remove such divs? Are there any functions in jquery to do it? thanks in advance

Comment: _Do_ those `<span>`s have a `title` or _should_ they have one? What is the expected result? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can target these elements with `$('div > span > span')`, and loop over them with **[`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/)**.

You can get the text content with the **[`.text()`](https://api.jquery.com/text/)** method, and delete the elements with **[`.remove()`](https://api.jquery.com/remove/)**.

This can be seen in the following:

```js
$('div > span > span').each(function() {
  console.log($(this).text());
  $(this).remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <span>
    <a href="#">link</a>
</span>
</div>

<div>
  <span>
    <span title="title 1">Some text written here</span>
  </span>
</div>

<div>
  <span>
    <span title="title 2">Some other text written here</span>
  </span>
</div>

<div>
  <span>
    <a href="#">some link</a>
</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I think it should be `div > span > span[title]` to select the spans that have title attribute and `this.parentElement.parentElement.remove()` to remove the div instead of the span.

Comment: ^ Equally valid. It depends on the *specific* use case as to which would be better, but both approaches will work for the OP's code :)

Answer (score 1):

Since there's no other text inside, you can simply use `.textContent` on the outer divs and `trim` the result:

```js
const texts = [];
document.querySelectorAll('div').forEach(div => {
  if (
    div.children[0].tagName !== 'SPAN' ||
    div.children[0].children[0].tagName !== 'SPAN' ||
    !div.children[0].children[0].hasAttribute('title')
  ){
    return;
  }
  texts.push(div.textContent.trim());
  // if you want to remove the divs afterwards:
  div.remove();
});
console.log(texts);
```

```html
<div>
<span>
<a href="#">
  link</a>
</span>
</div>

<div>
<span>
<span title=" title 1">
Some text written here
</span>
</span>
</div>

<div>
<span>
<span title="title 2">
Some other text written here
</span>
</span>
</div>

<div>
<span>
<span>
some span without a title
</span>
</span>
</div>

<div>
<span>
<a href="#">
some link
</a>
</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thankyou @CeritanPerformance for the answer but I want to remove divs that only has nested spans inside it and innermost span must have a title as I specified above.

Comment: Oh, I see. Edited

Answer (score 0):

No need for jQuery for this one and selected answer does not check for title attribute and does not remove he div (it removes the span):

```js
const data = Array.from(
  document.querySelectorAll("#content>div>span>span[title]")
).map(
  span=>[span.parentElement.parentElement,span.textContent.trim()]
);

console.log(
  "text content of element(s):",
  JSON.stringify(
    data.map(([x,text])=>text)
  )
);
setTimeout(
  ()=>{
    alert("before removing divs (check html)");
    data.forEach(([div])=>div.remove());
  },2000
)
```

```html
    <div id="content">

      <div>
        <span>
        <a href="#">
          link</a>
        </span>
        </div>
        
        <div>
        <span>
        <span title=" title 1">
        Some text written here
        </span>
        </span>
        </div>
        
        <div>
        <span>
        <span title="title 2">
        Some other text written here
        </span>
        </span>
        </div>
        
        <div>
        <span>
        <a href="#">
        some link
        </a>
        </span>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Yes thank you @HMR I updated jquery code to delete the div instead of span

Comment: actually, I am trying to do it entirely with JQuery instead of js. So this helped me